# How to put ParseQuery in seperate class and call this method in every activity in android?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

i'm new to android and coding in general

i have many textviews in my app so i'm retrieving string from parse and displaying it in textview.

i'm using the following parse query

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("Topics");
    query.getInBackground("fRGt3oz8af", new GetCallback<ParseObject>(){
        public void done(ParseObject arg0, ParseException arg1) {

            if (arg1==null)
            {
                    subTopicName = arg0.getString("class_1");
                    textView.setText("" + subTopicName);

            }

            else
            {
                Log.d("topic", "Error: " + arg1.getMessage());
            }

}});
```

since i've many textview i have to repeat the same code for retrieve each string. so i'm trying to avoid code redundancy.

my question is  how can i put the above query in different java class and call that method for retrieving each strings? or is there different method way to do it. I've never worked on parse server before so I'm really struggling with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which params might change? ParseObject, "Topics", "fRGt3oz8af" etc.

Comment: yea i'm currently trying to retrieve string if "fRGt3oz8af" changes to another objectid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
interface ParseCallback {
    void onComplete(String result);
    //todo onError() ?
}

protected void parse(ParseCallback callback) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Topics");
    query.getInBackground("fRGt3oz8af", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject arg0, ParseException arg1) {
            if (arg1 == null) {
                String subTopicName = arg0.getString("class_1");
                if (subTopicName != null) {
                    callback.onComplete(subTopicName);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("topic", "Error: " + arg1.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

public void example() {
    parse(result -> {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            myTextView.setText(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create observer pattern and on implementing the interface callback function you will able to get notified in your UI.

i.e. Create a new class extending ParseQuery and override done function. Create an interface in this class and call the interface function inside done function. Then implement this interface in your Activity class and update the UI.

Hope it give you some idea on how to achieve what you are looking for.